# How to remove %27A=0 from Url through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am finding strange character in url

```
%27A=0
```

Its either coming in middle or in between or end of url
How to escape and remove through htaccess the url having %27A=0 
Server is running on apache and nginx

Comment: You may want to figure out where your HTML or JS has a single quote instead of an ampersand instead of trying to work around the issue.

Comment: Thanks - i tried, but could not find the source,. Site build on joomla. Is there any suggestion on htaccess front

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove %27 (html escape for ampersend) from url with this line

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)'=0(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks - but will it remove A=0 also as mentioned in question